# Warning: implicit declaration of function only when using -std=c99

Tags: c, linux

I have a program that uses the <stdio.h> function dprintf. If I complie this without -std=c99 I have no problems, however if I try to compile wih this flag I'll get the "implicit function declaration" warning

Does this mean that dprintf is not declared in <stdio.h> for c99? If so, where is the function declaration?

Comment: `dprintf` is not a standard C function.

Comment: Please post your code, I think you are just missing an #include <stdio.h>. (Oh well , year Weather Vane is even more right, I didn't saw that d. So its just implementation defined behaviour of non standard functions)

Comment: What happens if you compile with `-std=gnu99`?

Comment: @WeatherVane it's dprintf(3), does that not make it a C standard function?

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio `dprintf` is not in C99. It's only in recent versions of POSIX.

Comment: It's not in C11 either, I haven't looked in C17.

Comment: @WeatherVane It wouldn't be. It prints to a file descriptor, which is not a thing in non-POSIX C.

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio See the "CONFORMING TO" section: "*The dprintf() and vdprintf() functions were originally GNU extensions that were later standardized in POSIX.1-2008.*"

Comment: Also see the [`dprintf(3)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dprintf) and the Feature Test Macro Requirements section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dprintf` is a Posix function, making it an extension to standard C.

Posix (and other) extension functions need to be enabled by defining an appropriate [feature test macro](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) before including any standard header. On Linux , at least, you'll find the appropriate feature test macro listed in the manpage, right after the prototype. For example, [man dprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) tells you:

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
>   dprintf(), vdprintf():
>      Since glibc 2.10:
>           _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
>       Before glibc 2.10:
>          _GNU_SOURCE
> ```

That means that, assuming that you are using a not too ancient glibc version, your file should start:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
```

Although you can achieve the same effect on gcc by using non-standard `-std` options, using feature test macros correctly makes your code portable between different Posix implementations.

Answer (score 3):

`dprintf` is not in C99. It's only in recent versions of POSIX.

You can compile with `-std=gnu99` to include both C99 and POSIX functions (plus some extensions).